# Tuning parameters for particle filtering with PCL

Tags: c++, ros, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, pcl

I am working on 3D point cloud object tracking(a cylindrical object) using particle filter in PCL(Point Cloud Library). The documentation does not quiet explains about the parameters on how it influences the results. I have done some study about the particle filter, but most of the parameters particle filter and coherence(I suppose the coherence here corresponds to the likelihood function) are specific to point cloud object tracking rather than robot localization.

```
std::vector<double> default_step_covariance = std::vector<double> (6, 0.015 * 0.015);
  default_step_covariance[3] *= 40.0;
  default_step_covariance[4] *= 40.0;
  default_step_covariance[5] *= 40.0;

  std::vector<double> initial_noise_covariance = std::vector<double> (6, 0.00001);
  std::vector<double> default_initial_mean = std::vector<double> (6, 0.0);

  KLDAdaptiveParticleFilterOMPTracker<RefPointType, ParticleT>::Ptr tracker
    (new KLDAdaptiveParticleFilterOMPTracker<RefPointType, ParticleT> (8));

  ParticleT bin_size;
  bin_size.x = 0.1f;
  bin_size.y = 0.1f;
  bin_size.z = 0.1f;
  bin_size.roll = 0.1f;
  bin_size.pitch = 0.1f;
  bin_size.yaw = 0.1f;


  //Set all parameters for  KLDAdaptiveParticleFilterOMPTracker
  tracker->setMaximumParticleNum (1000);
  tracker->setDelta (0.99);
  tracker->setEpsilon (0.2);
  tracker->setBinSize (bin_size);

  //Set all parameters for  ParticleFilter
  tracker_ = tracker;
  tracker_->setTrans (Eigen::Affine3f::Identity ());
  tracker_->setStepNoiseCovariance (default_step_covariance);
  tracker_->setInitialNoiseCovariance (initial_noise_covariance);
  tracker_->setInitialNoiseMean (default_initial_mean);
  tracker_->setIterationNum (1);
  tracker_->setParticleNum (600);
  tracker_->setResampleLikelihoodThr(0.00);
  tracker_->setUseNormal (false);


  //Setup coherence object for tracking
  ApproxNearestPairPointCloudCoherence<RefPointType>::Ptr coherence
    (new ApproxNearestPairPointCloudCoherence<RefPointType>);

  DistanceCoherence<RefPointType>::Ptr distance_coherence
    (new DistanceCoherence<RefPointType>);
  coherence->addPointCoherence (distance_coherence);

  pcl::search::Octree<RefPointType>::Ptr search (new pcl::search::Octree<RefPointType> (0.01));
  coherence->setSearchMethod (search);
  coherence->setMaximumDistance (0.01);

  tracker_->setCloudCoherence (coherence);
```

This code is taken from [PCL particle filter example](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/tracking.html). There are parameters defined for number of Particles twice in KLD Adaptive Particle Filter OMP Tracker and Particle filter(setMaximumParticleNum and setParticleNum). The bin size, covariance, delta, epsilon and all the other parameters on what it does or how it influences the results. Any explanation, research papers or sources of any kind will be really helpful. Thanks !!!!

P.S: The PCL Q&A forum is not up.

Comment: Can you summary what you'd want, because I am not sure to understand. You want an explanation of different parameters ?

Comment: @Gaston, Sorry for not being so clear. Yeah an explanation about the various parameters used in particle filter like what the parameter is and  how it influences the result. For example, `tracker_->setIterationNum (1);` is the number of iterations for the algorithm to perform, which may yield better tracking of objects with the trade-off of reducing performance.